# Правильно ли я понял насчет запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, и

Есть два предложения, соединенные союзом "и":
**Море глухо роптало, и волны бились о берег бешено и гневно.**

Правильна ли пунктуация, если я напишу по-другому?
**Мы жили там, где море глухо роптало и волны бились о берег бешено и гневно.**

Если нет, то объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5):

Вы всё правильно поняли насчёт запятой.

Было сложносочинённое предложение без каких либо общих членов - запятая перед союзом ставится.

Во втором случае, где Вы не поставили запятую, у предложений, составляющих ССП, появилось то общее, что отменяет запятую: главное предложение.

Так же отменяют запятую общее придаточное, вводное слово или оборот, обстоятельство (или другой общий второстепенный член предложения).

---

> Запятая перед одиночным соединительным союзом ***и*** не ставится в
>   следующих случаях:
>
> а) простые предложения в составе сложносочинённого предложения имеют
>   **общий второстепенный член**:
>
> ***Вскоре после восхода*** набежала туча и брызнул короткий дождь (Пушкин) (общий второстепенный член – обстоятельство времени вскоре
>   после восхода, ср.: *Вскоре после восхода набежала туча; Вскоре после
>   восхода брызнул короткий дождь);*
>
> б) простые предложения в составе сложносочинённого предложения имеют
>   **общее придаточное предложение**:
>
> *Уже совсем рассвело и народ стал подниматься, когда я вернулся в свою комнату* (Л. Толстой) (придаточное времени когда я вернулся в свою
>   комнату является общим для обеих частей сложносочинённого предложения,
>   ср.: *Уже совсем рассвело, когда я вернулся в свою комнату; Народ стал
>   подниматься, когда я вернулся в свою комнату);*
>
> в) простые предложения сложносочинённого предложения вместе поясняют
>   **общее для них третье предложение, предшествующее им и связанное с ними бессоюзной связью**:
>
> *Он чувствовал себя нехорошо: тело было слабо и в глазах ощущалась тупая боль* (Куприн) (части сложносочинённого предложения: *Тело было
>   слабо; В глазах ощущалась тупая боль* – поясняют смысл общего для них
>   первого простого предложения, связанного с ними бессоюзно: *Он
>   чувствовал себя нехорошо*);
>
> г) простые предложения в составе сложносочинённого предложения имеют
>   **общее вводное слово, вводное словосочетание или предложение**:
>
> *По словам охотников, зверь в этих лесах вывелся и птица исчезла* (источник сообщения – по словам охотников – один и тот же для всего
>   высказывания, ср.: *По словам охотников, зверь в этих лесах вывелся;
>   По словам охотников, птица исчезла*).

---

Подробнее - см. **[источник](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/733-12_znaki_prepinaniya_v_slozhnosochinennyh_predlozheniyah.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

1) **Море глухо роптало, и волны бились о берег бешено и гневно.**

Сложносочиненное предложение (ССП), запятая перед союзом И ставится, пауза делается.

2) **Мы жили там, где море глухо роптало и волны бились о берег бешено и гневно.**

Сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с однородными придаточными, соединенными одиночным союзом И, запятая не ставится, пауза не делается.

**Это правило,** а объяснить его можно так: придаточные предложения произносятся в одну фразу, так как относятся к одному главному предложению (оно объединяет их).